# Ubuntu Server 18.04 = Ubuntu Desktop - all GUI and other stuff?

Tags: server

I have read [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F), and both versions use the same kernel. It also said that installation process is different, but I do not care about that.

Is there anything that is not included or disabled by default on Desktop but is included and enabled on Server? I mean, I did not like the default desktop environment of the Desktop version, but it seemed that I could not remove it even after installing other desktop environment, so I installed the Server edition, and then installed a desktop environment and lightdm, and it looks as if it were Desktop edition. But I wonder if there are some server features in the server edition that are not needed for desktop and therefore not included in the desktop edition.

PS: The duplicate page just showed the same content as the FAQ page I mentioned. But what I am asking is if the server edition has some features or settings that the desktop edition does not have. Server 18.04 did not ask for specific server features when installing, unlike a previous version of server edition, which asked if I wanted to use web server or something. That is, is it completely normal to install the server edition when one wants a desktop OS, only because he wants to start from the bare minimum and then add the stuff he wants, not the other way around (install the desktop edition and then remove the stuff he does not want)?

Comment: Yes, I remember that with the previous version of the Server edition. But with 18.04, it did not ask that.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference between the desktop and server editions by downloading and comparing the `.manifest` files on the [18.04 download page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/).

There are many tools to do this, I like [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) (it's in the standard repos)

There are lots of differences, here's the first page of the comparison.

[image]